# No sound since upgrade to 17.04

Tags: sound, 17.04

I have no sound since I upgraded to 17.04. I have been looking online for some sort of fix, but nothing yet. I switched from Windows operating system about a year ago when I bought a new computer (I hate Windows), so I am still learning Ubuntu and am not an expert.

Any help would be appreciated, it stinks not having sound :(

Comment: Have you checked your Sound Settings to make sure that the proper output device is selected, and that the sound is not muted, and that the volume is high enough?

Comment: Yes, I checked all of the obvious things. The only option under settings is "Dummy Output"